# Will my home router user/admin password be any protection against hackers?

Tags: router, security, wireless-router

I'm in Australia, I have "Fiber To The Home". This passes through the NBN box on the outside wall, to the NBN modem inside the wall, and thence to my mid-range ASUS AC1900 Dual Band router. Firmware has been upgraded to 2020-ish but I intend to upgrade to the latest in a couple of weeks.

All known devices/MAC adresses have been itemised in the DHCP.  Some of these are WiFi connections.  I do not use the WPS button at any time, ever.  NAT is on, UpnP is off.  Port Forwarding is on, NAT Passthrough is off.

The Admin password is (IMHO) reasonably strong, >10 characters @ 96 density (soon to be upgraded, will be longer), the PSKs very much stronger. All are randomly generated in my spreadsheet. The router is routinely offed for 10 minutes at the end of every month.

Is there anything I need to do to improve security against external attackers that does not involve air-gapping the router from the real world?

---

Thank you for the interest you have shown.  I have learnt a few things I did not know before, and the security solutions are nowhere near as fearsome as I had imagined.

Comment: Turn off remote access except if you need it for a special time.

Comment: Aaahh, would that be Windows Remote Access?  If so, I've never had it switched on, too dangerous.

Comment: No, remote administrative access to the router. Usually allows connecting to the router from outside, eg. from the wan port.

Comment: Thank you for that.  According to the manual, I need UPnP for that, but since I've not enabled it... (I did edit that into the original post, probably as you were responding to my previous comment.)

Comment: To start with: What kind of external attackers? One who's on the other side of the internet, or one who's sitting in a car in your street? One who's trying to hack you specifically, or one who's just randomly poking at anything that comes up?

Comment: I would not rely on UPnP being off for being protected against remote access to the web console. If there's an option to disable it, disable it. A bug in the firmware or something else might still work without you knowing.

Comment: @u1686 Ummm.  At the moment, anyone.  TBH, I know I am special, but the attacker wants control of my computer rather than my wealth. So the threat could come from anywhere.  One extra defense is my low transmit power - in early versions I could set a very low percentage, just enough to reach the daughter's bedroom and drop dead from exhaustion as it fell out of the window.  In later versions, it's less granular.

Comment: @LPChip Firmware bugs.  Yeah, but I guess upgrades/updates are the only defence there.

Comment: Signal strength is not much a defense. If there really is someone who's interested in hacking you specifically, they'll just get a cheap *directional* antenna and will be able to pick the signal up half a mile away. (Then the question is what it's supposed to defend *against.* Given up-to-date firmware with the WPA2 issues patched, the signal doesn't matter, and if the firmware wasn't patched, the signal would make an incredibly weak defense, so I think you really need to hire someone to tell you that you need to decide on your threat model or something.)

Comment: To get the most security-wise from a router, flashing OpenWrt or DD-WRT would be recommended if either supports the AC1900 - OpenWrt guarantees at least two releases a year so the device is always up to date with security patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a few things to increase router security:

1. Disable remote administration - Only people inside your network can change it's settings
2. Use strong passwords - Changing as often as you feel is needed
3. Make sure your router's firmware is up to date and still under support.  If not, you could be vulnerable to exploits
4. Enable MAC address filtering - If supported by your router, only known MAC addresses can connect to it

Comment: Some routers also allow disabling admin on the Wi-Fi interface.